# Firebase database not working with Facebook Expo authentication

Tags: ios, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo, facebook-authentication

I've been developing an app with React Native (with Expo) and Firebase on the backend. When running the project through Expo client on the iPhone, I can normally login with email and password and then fetch data from Firebase database. But when I login with Facebook, database read hands and it does not resolve anything. Important parts of the code look following:

```
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// This works everywhere
export const login = async (email, password) => {
    await firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);

    const userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;

    return userId + '';
};

export const loginByFacebook = async () => {
  const { type, token } = await Expo.Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync(FB_APP_ID, {
    permissions: ['public_profile'],
  });

  if (type === 'success') {
    const credential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(token);

    try {
      await firebase.auth().signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(credential);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('cannot login ', error);
    }
  }
};

export const readData = (key) => {
  console.log('getWins ');
  const userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;

  return firebase
    .database()
    .ref(`/${key}/${userId}`)
    .once('value');
};

...

class PostList extends React.Component {
    async componentDidMount() {
        // it normally resolves when logged with email & password,
        // resolves with facebook auth on iPhone simulator
        // does not resolve with facebook auth on Expo client on iPhone
        const data = await readData('posts');
    }
}
```

However, what is really strange, that it does not work on iPhone + Expo client, but does on the iPhone simulator. The crucial part is in the `async componentDidMount()`.

Database config is still in the dev mode (allow all read & writes):

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": true
    }
}
```

I've used the following guides: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/facebook
https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/using-firebase#listening-for-authentication

Are there any more prerequisites that I've forgotten to setup? Or Expo client has limitations in terms of properly handling calls with Facebook auth?